# dll and class like features in c#

Tags: c#, class, dll

i'm  created several utilities for attendance machines (like face Reader and other) now i'm making every thing in one application. But the main data fetching part is different.

here my question is i got two options to do that

1. by creating 'dll' for each device main functionality
2. by creating class

is there any other options for above like features

Comment: The way I look at this is, will the Functionality of each Reader change? Will you need to re-use the code in another application, if yes then move into a seperate dll.

Comment: Namespaces and classes are very different things... you could create several classes within the same namespace if you wanted, either in the same assembly or different ones...

Comment: all other code for all devices is same the part of code which differs for that i want one good feature and i'll replace that part for each device every time

Comment: you're really comparing apples and oranges here. whether to put something into a dll is unrelated to it being a class. You can put plain functions in dlls as well.

Comment: i wanted to use any one feature like if i use class means i'll create one one class for each device to handle that differing code or if i'm using 'dll' then i'll create one one dll for each. And now i'm asking except this any other features that i can use instead of above mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need a new class for each device.

You probably also want a different DLL for each, but this depends on your exact requirements not explained here.  Also, moving classes between DLLs is relatively easy compared to moving behavior between classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you anticipate extending these devices in the future, I will create a base DLL that contains common device code, and then a separate DLL for each unique device.

If these devices are not very extensible, then use a separate class in the same DLL.